# What's the point of stringdampers in 3D shooting

Tags: archery, bows, 3d-archery

I see a lot of (traditional) archers shooting 3D with stringdampers attached. As far as I know they slow your bow down. Okay, okay, it's minimal, but still... Also, as far as I know, the 3D targets don't hear anything ;).

So, is there any reason - besides the style - to have them attached?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes down to a few things. Some people like adding things to their bows. If it can fit on it they will have it. I once saw someone using a recurve with 9 stabilisers.

Others like to pretend they are hunting without the actual death bit. Quite a few 3D target shooters follow a course which simulates a hunt.

They could also be hunters and just leave it on their bow regardless if they are hunting.

The last most common category is the person has no idea what it is. Some poor soul I knew once brought one because the seller convinced him it would 'make his arrows go faster. '